# Can a BAR of a PCIe device be fully/partially mapped to multiple userspace processes?

Tags: linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e, memory-mapping

In a linux device driver (kernel 4.x) - is it possible to remap the same BAR of a PCIe device multiple times to be used by different userspace processes?

If possible - can the mappings differ in size and offset? So I for example map one chunk to one process to one process, s second chunk to 2 other processes and a chunk overlapping the first chunk to a fourth process?

Comment: PCIe BAR space will be exposed in /sys as "resource X". You can map that using mmap() from user space process. You can call mmap() from multiple process. Please try that once.

Comment: Yes, you can, but everything needs to be page-aligned. Your driver may need to get creative with the interpretation of mmap offset if you want to the user to choose both BAR and offset within BAR.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for replying! I had a hard time figuring out whether this would work or not. I was affraid that it was depending on the platform implementation of the IOMMU.